# (Question about proof ) If $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x \cdot y) = f(x)f(y)$, then $f(x)=x$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, then $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$for all $x$ and $y$and also $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$. Now suppose that $f$ satisfies these two properties, but that $f(x)$ is not always $0$. Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

$(a),(b),(c)$, and $(d)$ are results that follow from $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(x \cdot y) = f(x)f(y)$

$(a)$ $f(1)=1$.

$(b)$ $f(x)=x$ for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$.

$(c)$ $f(x)>0$ whenever $x>0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$(d)$ $f(x)>f(y)$ whenever $x>y$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

> Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.
>
> FACT: Between any two real numbers there is a rational number.
>
> Since we have shown in part $(b)$ that $f(x)=x$ for all rational $x$, it is enough to consider irrational numbers. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ be an irrational number. We also assume that $x>0$. Then we wish to show that $f(x)=x$. If possible suppose that $f(x) \ne x$. Then since $x \ne 0$ implies $f \ne 0$ (from part $c$) and hence either $f(x)>x$ or $f(x)<x$.
>
> Case $I$ $(f(x)>x)$:
>
> Let $f(x)>x$. Then from the FACT above we have a rational number, say $y$, between $x$ and $f(x)$, that is, $x<y<f(x)$. Then since $x<y$ from part $(d)$ we have that $f(x)<f(y)=y$ as $y$ is rational and from part $(b)$ we have that $f(y)=y$. Thus we have $f(x)<y$ and $f(x)>y$ which can not happen simultaneously. Therefore, $f(x)=x$.

The case where $f(x)<x$ is similar. I wanted to know if it's enough to assume for the sake of contradiction that $f(x) \ne x$ and hence $f(x) >x$ and $f(x)<x$? I'm not sure how $f \ne 0$ is used in the proof.

Comment: Well, to get $f(1)=1$ you must choose $y$ with $f(y)\neq 0$ and then write $f(y)=f(1\times y)=f(1)\times f(y)$ and divide by $f(y)$ (which you couldn't do if $f(y)=0$).

Comment: Even though it's not written above, that's the general idea behind the proof in part $(a)$. Although there's no dividing happening in the proof that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, so I'm not sure if that's just extra information.

Comment: Not following.  From $f(1)=1$ you quickly get that $f(n)=n$ for all integers, and then $f(x)=x$ for all rationals.  That's big, and it all comes from $f(1)=1$.

Comment: To get $f(1)=1$, we can do it in this way: $f(1)=f(1\cdot1)=(f(1))^2$ implies $f(1)=0$ or $f(1)=1$. If $f(1)=0$ then for any $y\in\mathbb R$, $f(y)=f(1\cdot y)=f(1)f(y)=0$ so $f=0$. If we assume $f$ is not always equal to $0$, we must have $f(1)=1$.

Comment: @lulu: I think you're referring to the proof that $f(x)=x$ for all rationals instead of the proof that $f(x)=x$ for any $x$( rational and irrational).

Comment: Still not following.  You said "I'm not sure how $f\neq 0$ is used in the proof."  I pointed out that from the assumption that $f\neq 0$ we very quickly get $f(x)=x$ at least for rationals.  So that assumption is used in a big way.  To finish you then need to work a little harder.

Comment: How do you get (c)?

Comment: @Y.Forman  Say $x>0$.  Then $f(x)=f\left(\sqrt x\right)^2>0$.

Comment: @lulu I see how to get $\geq0$, but not $>0$

Comment: @Y.Forman  Well, $1=f(1)=f(x)\times f\left( \frac 1x\right)$ shows that $x\neq 0\implies f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: @lulu Got it, thanks.